# JWK not found in Quarkus

Tags: jwt, quarkus, jwk

I am trying to see if I can substitute an old service with a new one that uses Quarkus.
Todo so I need to be able to check some properties of the JWT that are sent with the request Authorization as a bearer token.

My problem is that after going over several docs and [this tutorial](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect) I am still not able to get this working.

**The case**

So I have a FusionAuth server that provides a JWT token that is signed using an HS256 algorithm, and thus I have a `kid` set and a secret used to sign it.

**The Problem**

Even after trying all possible combinations of configurations on the `application.properties` file I still keep getting this message:

```
Token verification has failed: Unable to process JOSE object (cause: org.jose4j.lang.UnresolvableKeyException: JWK with kid '3808b7397' is not available): JsonWebSignature{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"3808b7397"}->...
```

I am not an expert on this subject, but I inherited this from someone that left the company so I cannot have any support and I am trying to read and understand as much as I can. (I apologize for the mistakes or misuses of terms)

As far as I understand I need to be able to tell which is the correct key for that `kid`

This is what I have tried on the properties (with some redacted values of course):

```
quarkus.keycloak.devservices.enabled=false
quarkus.oidc.devui.grant.type=client

quarkus.oidc.credentials.jwt.issuer=<<MY_ISSUER>>
quarkus.oidc.credentials.jwt.signature-algorithm=HS256
quarkus.oidc.credentials.jwt.key-id=3808b7397
quarkus.oidc.credentials.jwt.key-password=<<MY_PASSWORD>>

quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=<<MY_FUSIONAUTH_SERVER>>

#quarkus.oidc.token.allow-jwt-introspection=false
#quarkus.oidc.token.allow-opaque-token-introspection=false

quarkus.log.level=DEBUG
```